# jQuery - if/else statement is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to get an if/else statement to work in jQuery.
Based on what users choose on our platform .card-decorator-brand-curve gets added with either card-decorator-stroke or card-decorator-stroke-none.

card-decorator-stroke works how I want it but card-decorator-stroke-none doesn't.

JS Below:

```js
$('.card-decorator-brand-curve').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('card-decorator-stroke')) {
        $(this).removeClass('card-decorator-stroke');
        $(this).addClass('brand-curve-stroke');
        console.log("test me");
   } else {
    $(".card-decorator-stroke-none").removeClass('brand-curve-stroke');
        console.log("test me 2");
    }
 });
```

Any help to assist me to make this fix is gladly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).find('card-decorator-stroke')` returns a jQuery object which is always truthy.

```
if($(this).find('card-decorator-stroke').length)
```

Comment: If .card-decorator-brand-curve is added with card-decorator-stroke-none how do I get that working? It's not working for me. I need removeClass('brand-curve-stroke') to happen when card-decorator-stroke-none is added.

Comment: Answered my own question! Nevermind. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My brain might be fried from coding all day but I finally figured it out.

```js
 $('.card-decorator-brand-curve').each(function() {
         if ($('.card-decorator-brand-curve').hasClass('card-decorator-stroke')){
             $('.card-decorator-brand-curve').addClass('brand-curve-stroke');
             $('.card-decorator-brand-curve').removeClass('card-decorator-stroke');
             console.log('test');
         } else {
             $('.card-decorator-stroke-none').removeClass('brand-curve-stroke');
             console.log('test me');
           }
});
```